# Extracting Text in R from checkbox sort of format

Tags: regex, r

I have text like the following:

```
x<-"Annual Turnover in Crores   ( )15-25Lacs ( )25-50 Lacs ( )50-75 Lacs ( )75Lacs to 1 Cr ( X ) 1-10 Cr ( )10-25Cr ( )25-50Cr ( )Above 50 Crs"
```

Now as we can see that there's a check before the 1-10 Cr box. How can I get R to extract the value which has the box checked?

I am using

a<-sub(".*.\(X).*",x)

Comment: Try: `regmatches(x,regexpr("(?<=\\( X \\))[^\\(]+",x,perl=TRUE))`. This works if the element checked is after exactly `( X )` (note the blank spaces).

Comment: Thanx a lot. Worked like a charm

Comment: @nicola...can u please tell me what is the logic behind all the symbols you have used. will help me in future .

Comment: I made some explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want through a simple pattern in a regex:

```
regmatches(x,regexpr("(?<=\\( X \\))[^\\(]+",x,perl=TRUE))
#[1] " 1-10 Cr "
```

Here is how the pattern is build.

- The `(?<=something)` tells to look for the part of the string after `something`. In this case, we want to look after `( X )`. Since the `()` symbols are special characters in regex, I had to escape them thorugh `\\`.
- the `[^\\(]+` part tells to get all the characters that are not `(`. This because the next "checkbox" value starts with a `(`. Again, I had to escape the symbol.
- the `perl=TRUE` argument is needed, otherwise the look behind defined at the start of the pattern won't be valid.

Hope this clarifies a little.

Comment: Is there a way to get the output like " Annual Turnover in Crores - 1-10 Cr "?